# Index was out of range after deleting multiple rows from the datagridview? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, datagridview, binary-search

I use an `ArrayList` for my binary search. The datagridview's rows is added to the ArryList. When I deleting a single row from the datagridview, it works almost perfectly. The problem is when I delete many rows from the datagridview from the top or the bottom and middle, it gives me an error. How can I refresh or update the `ArrayList` after I deleted a row from the `ArrayList` (datagridview)?

### The error:

> 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index'

---

### My code for copying rows to the ArrayList:

I put this code into the button `MouseEnter` event, so before I click on button to search it copies everything to the `ArrayList`.

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
{
   ArrayList[row.Index] = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
```

---

### My delete code for the selected row(s):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    return;
}
```

### My code for the binary search in winform:

```
int index = this.ArrayList.BinarySearch(textBoxBinarySearch.Text);
if (index > -1)
{
    dataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    dataGridView2.Rows[index].Selected = true;
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0];
    MessageBox.Show("Index is equal to: " + index, "Binary Search");
}
```

---

### The error is occuring at:

> ```
> dataGridView2.Rows[index].Selected = true;
> ```

---

### **After opening a csv, the binary search is working perfectly!**

[image]

### **Testing delete function.**

[image]

### **Removed more rows from the datagridview.**

[image]

### **After removed many rows from the datagridview, if I try to search for the name, the errors is appears.**

[image]

---

I hope I don't miss any information from my description. Thanks if you read it trough!

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Where's the 'delete' code?

Comment: Note that to use BinarySearch, the list should already be sorted

Comment: @rory.ap I updated my question

Comment: @DanielB Added to my question.

Comment: your deletion code removes only the first of the `SelectedRows`... is that intended?

Comment: @DanielB If I sort the ArrayList, it gives the same error.

Comment: do you really need to use BinarySearch?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use an `ArrayList` for my binary search. The datagridview's rows
>   is added to the ArryList. When I deleting a single row from the
>   datagridview, it works almost perfectly. The problem is when I delete
>   many rows from the datagridview from the top or the bottom and middle,
>   it gives me an error. How can I refresh or update the `ArrayList`
>   after I deleted a row from the `ArrayList` (datagridview)?

### Solution:

When I oppened two times the csv file, the binary search is worked well, but for the third time, it doesn't, because I had to clear my `ArrayList` with `ArrayList.Clear();` not just the datagridview. Then I could copy the datagridview rows to the empty `ArrayList`.

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
ArryList.Clear();
```

**Then ->**

### My code for copying rows to the ArrayList:

I put this code into the button `MouseEnter` event, so before I click on button to search it copies everything to the `ArrayList`.

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
{
   ArrayList[row.Index] = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
```

---

### My delete code for the selected row(s):

```
for (int i = dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{ 
      dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[i].Index);
      ListOfPeople.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

---

### My code for the binary search in winform:

```
int index = this.ArrayList.BinarySearch(textBoxBinarySearch.Text);
if (index > -1)
{
    dataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    dataGridView2.Rows[index].Selected = true;
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0];
    MessageBox.Show("Index is equal to: " + index, "Binary Search");
}
```

---

Thanks if you read it trough!

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that you're only removing items from the DataGridView but not from the ArrayList then using the arraylist search index against the DataGridView. So if you remove the last item from the DataGridView it still exists in the ArrayList so if you match on that item and attempt to use the index in the DataGridView you will get the index out of range exception.

If you have 10 items in the arraylist and the datagridview then delete 2 from the datagridview you now have 10 items in the arraylist and 8 in the datagridview. If you receive the index of the either of the last 2 items in the arraylist (8 or 9) and attempt to access items in those indicies in the datagridview it will throw the exception.

Try using data binding instead then operate only on the ArrayList.

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ArrayList;
```

Also, if you're looping over a list removing items do it backwards. Start at the item with the last item and work back to the start:

```
for(int i = dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[i].Index);
}
```

Doing a foreach causes the enumerator to throw an exception as the list has changed from one pass to the next.

Comment: I don't have all your code so I can't reproduce what you have. I have no idea what types of items your ArrayList contains. Also, you say it's not working for you, what isn't working?

Comment: It has a syntax error for `SelectedItems`, because it is not specified. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, should be SelectedRows not SelectedItems. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now it gives an error when I deleting a row with your code.: ` 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
`

Comment: Try putting `dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count - 1` in the for line.

Comment: Removing rows is working with your code now. How can I update the `ArrayList`? Still giving that error when I want to search with binary search. After deleting many rows.

Comment: You can do a `while` loop instead of a `for` and remove the first one: `while(dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count == 0){ dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Index);}`. It is easier and not error prone

Comment: @Galarist *....How can I update the ArrayList?*. Is it so difficult to think it your self? Just clear it and refill it as in your question *My code for copying rows to the ArrayList:*

Comment: @Galarist It **did** actually. It found your error and fixed it! Remember your title *Index was out of range after deleting multiple rows from the datagridview? C#*. You asked about why the index was out of range! Now you need other things. Ask a new question. Yours is being answered!

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε if I clear the `ArrayList` and then refill with my with that code. It gives that error again. My binary search still not working correctly.

Comment: @Galarist Show a **minimal working** example that **reproduces** the problem so we can test it ourselves.

Comment: @galarist Your ArrayList and dataGridView2 are not in sync. If you remove items from dataGridView2 you also need to remove them from ArrayList. If you sort ArrayList you need to sort dataGridView2 as well. As I said in my response, you need to look at data binding your ArrayList to dataGridView2 then when you remove items from ArrayList they'll also be removed from dataGridView2.

Comment: I fixed my problem, will post an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

I've put a quick way of doing this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopulateGrid();
    }

    private ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student {Lastname = "aa"},
            new Student {Lastname = "bb"},
            new Student {Lastname = "cc"},
            new Student {Lastname = "cc"},
            new Student {Lastname = "cc"},
            new Student {Lastname = "ee"},
            new Student {Lastname = "ff"},
            new Student {Lastname = "ff"},
            new Student {Lastname = "gg"},
            new Student {Lastname = "gg"},
        };

        dataGridView2.DataSource = students;
        myList = new ArrayList(students.Select(x => x.Lastname).ToList());
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var index = myList.BinarySearch(textBoxBinarySearch.Text);
        if(index > -1)
        {
            dataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
            dataGridView2.Rows[index].Selected = true;
            dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0];
            MessageBox.Show("Index is equal to: " + index, "Binary Search");
        }
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {

            var selected = dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0];
            students.RemoveAt(selected.Index);

            dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = students;
            myList = new ArrayList(students.Select(x => x.Lastname).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

But I would advise avoid using `ArrayList` since it's not strong type. Use `List<T>` instead. I guess the reason to use ArrayList is `BinarySearch` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not upvote you, but that's really works! So if I am right, I can the `DataSource ` to my imported csv, after if it's opened?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: the main reason that u r getting that exception is ListOfPeople is not in sync with grid rows. first remove form ListOfPeople then grid

Comment: Ah I am confused now. :D

Comment: why can't you use the way I delete an item? btnDelete_Click method

Comment: If I use that for delete function then I have reference error for the ".Lastname".

Comment: I fixed by myself.... Now it's working without any issue... I will post an aswer later.

Comment: Glad you figured out.